# Change raster cell values to NA if cell contains a point

Tags: r, raster, r-sp

I have a number of raster layers contained in a single `stack` as well as a `SpatialPoints` object containing point coordinates.  I am trying to change the value of the raster layers to NA if the cell contains a point.

I have provided a reproducible example below. However to put this in context, my real data consists of a 10 layers of 'habitat' (elevation, canopy cover, etc) that are all contained in a stack.  The `rasters` cover an area that is roughly 34 x 26 km. In addition I have ~10,000 GPS locations from animals.

So, for the reproducible example.

```
library(raster)
library(sp)
```

Make three `rasters` and combine them into a `stack`

```
set.seed(123)
r1 <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
r1 <- setValues(r1, sample(c(1:50), 100, replace = T))

r2 <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
r2 <- setValues(r2, sample(c(40:50), 100, replace = T))

r3 <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
r3 <- setValues(r3, sample(c(50:55), 100, replace = T))

Stack <- stack(r1, r2, r3)
nlayers(Stack)
```

Make the `SpatialPoints`

```
Pts <- SpatialPoints(data.frame(x = sample(-175:175, 50, replace = T),
                                y = sample(-75:75, 50, replace = T)))
```

Plot one of the rasters and the points

```
plot(Stack[[2]])
plot(Pts, add = T)
```

[image]

Now, is it possible to change the value of every cell that contains at least one point to NA?  It would be great to perform this operation on the `stack`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use `extract()`, which can be asked to return the cell number of the raster cell over which each point lies:

```
ii <- extract(Stack, Pts, cellnumbers=TRUE)[,"cells"]
Stack[ii] <- NA

## Check any one of the layers to see that this worked:
plot(Stack[[2]])
plot(Pts, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Alternatively, one could use `rasterize()`, though it'll likely (?) be slower for very large rasters:

```
ii <- !is.na(rasterize(Pts, Stack))
Stack[ii] <- NA
```

Comment: Cool.  Very helpful.  Is there a reason you indexed layer `[[1]]` in the `Stack`?  Testing this out, it seems like you could perform the operation on the entire stack at once.  e.g. `ii <- unique(extract(Stack, Pts, cellnumbers=TRUE)[,"cells"])`
`Stack[ii] <- NA`

Comment: @B.Davis No great reason, and in fact the call to `unique()` isn't needed either. I've edited the post to simplify accordingly.